# Eclipse C/C++ not including files at build time

Tags: c, eclipse, window, include-path, stm32

i am trying to program an STM32f discovery board in eclipse c/c++ but I get an error that says

```
In file included from src/tsl_user.c:28:0:
inc/tsl_user.h:32:17: fatal error: tsl.h: No such file or directory
```

This is a library from STM. It is included in a sub folder /Libraries/STMDriver/
and in this folder there are two folders for includes and source.

I have a lot around to add these folders to the project includes to see these folders but it is still giving me an error. I can CTRL+Click on the header and it opens the correct header file location, it is just not including it at compile.

What else can i do to get eclipse to see these files at build?

Answer (score 0):

There are certain settings for the project. You can access it by right clicking your project in the project explorer and choosing properties. In the properties window, go to C/C++ general, Paths and Symbols. Make sure you have all you need included in the Includes and Source Location tabs. It's a good idea to add something like

```
/${ProjName}/src
```

Just change "src" to anything you need